# grep to select strings that contains certain words

Tags: regex, grep

I have a list:

```
/device1/element1/CmdDiscovery
/device1/element1/CmdReaction
/device1/element1/Direction
/device1/element1/MS-E2E003-COM14/Field2
/device1/element1/MS-E2E003-COM14/Field3
/device1/element1/MS-E2E003-COM14/NRepeatLeft
```

How can I `grep` so that the returned strings containing only `"Field" followed by digits` or simply `NRepeatLeft` at the end of string *(in my example it will be the last three strings)*?

Expected output:

```
/device1/element1/MS-E2E003-COM14/Field2
/device1/element1/MS-E2E003-COM14/Field3
/device1/element1/MS-E2E003-COM14/NRepeatLeft
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
grep -E "(Field[0-9]*|NRepeatLeft$)" file.txt
      |  |           |           ||
      |  |          OR   end_line |
      | opening_choice   closing_choice
 extented_grep
```

if you don't have `-E` switch (stands for **ERE** : *Extented Regex Expression*):

```
grep "\(Field[0-9]*\|NRepeatLeft$\)" file.txt
```

**OUTPUT**

```
/device1/element1/MS-E2E003-COM14/Field2
/device1/element1/MS-E2E003-COM14/Field3
/device1/element1/MS-E2E003-COM14/NRepeatLeft
```

That will `grep` for lines matching `Field[0-9]` or lines matching `RepeatLeft` at the end. Is it what you expect ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not much sure of how to use grep for your purpose.Probably you would like perl for this:

```
perl -lne 'if(/Field[\d]+/ or /NRepeatLeft/){print}' your_file
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$ grep -E '(Field[0-9]*|NRepeatLeft)$' file.txt
```

Output:

```
/device1/element1/MS-E2E003-COM14/Field2
/device1/element1/MS-E2E003-COM14/Field3
/device1/element1/MS-E2E003-COM14/NRepeatLeft
```

Explanation:

```
Field       # Match the literal word
[0-9]*      # Followed by any number of digits
|           # Or
NRepeatLeft # Match the literal word
$           # Match the end of the string
```

You can see how this works with your example [here](http://rubular.com/r/K0NgOJU2L5).

Comment: ERE is not PCRE or Perl, `(?:)` is NOT a valid construct in ERE.